What are the character limitations of a SchemaName in the AWS Schema Registry?
What are the limiations of the SchemaName within AWS Glue Schema Registry? In particular I would like to know:

What is the maximum character limit for a schema name?

I ask because the TopicRecordNameStrategy could potentially lead to very long subject names.


Does the name have to follow a specific character set (ASCII/UTF8)?
Can it start with a number?
Any other limitations with the name which should be known?

For reference: I asked the same question for the confluent schema registry here.
